# Not able to boot system after changing plymouth theme

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, plymouth

I was customizing Plymouth and I rebooted to check if it was working and after selecting Ubuntu from grub(I have dualboot system with windows), I entered a black screen with a underscore static on it. I pressed Ctrl+Alt+F2 and it started blinking. After a lot of reading online. I booted from a live usb to update grub and rebooted only to enter windows.

Then I read somewhere to replace `quiet splash` with `text` and doing so resulted in a successful boot.

I removed the Plymouth theme and updated the `default.plymouth` to auto to make things as they were.

I repaired Grub again and after doing so I rebooted and encountered the blinking underscore/cursor again. I now have to replace quiet splash everytime to boot.

I know that it is not a problem with Nvidia drivers because in the successful boot situation I check under it under settings.

Please help, I need an alternate solution to this.
Thank you for your time.

EDIT - This is what I did exactly:

from !https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1009320/

Plymouth of OS X Yosemite 10.10

### Installation:

1)_ Copy darwin folder (uncompressed from tar.gz) to /lib/plymouth/themes/

2)_ Run these commands:
$ `sudo update-alternatives --install /lib/plymouth/themes/default.plymouth default.plymouth /lib/plymouth/themes/darwin/darwin.plymouth 100`

$ `sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth`
(choose the plymouth number)

$ `sudo update-initramfs -u`

There was no darwin in `/lib/plymouth/themes/darwin/darwin.plymouth`, so I created these directories and pasted it there.

After that I rebooted to check if it works but instead ,my boot was messed up.

What I did then:

1. Went into recovery mode and deleted plymouth theme and updated using `sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth` . Made it default.

2.Rebooted to the blinking cursor again. Saw this video !https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x-8RfSdcl0o where the first solution is to replace `quiet splash` with `text`. Booted gain successfuly

3. Used the boot-repair software to repair grub. Didn't work.
4. So now I have to edit the grub file every time I boot.

EDIT 2:

1. Just removed quiet splash(did not replace it with text), and Ubuntu booted successfully.
   I have no clue of what is happening

Comment: Can you explain what changes you made step by step ?

Comment: @KetanPatel I've made the corresponding edits in my question. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You messed up your system boot by doing mistake in this step.

```
There was no darwin in /lib/plymouth/themes/darwin/darwin.plymouth, so I created these directories and pasted it there.
```

It seems you copy pasted command without knowing correct path of plymouth themes in your system. There was no issue with grub bootloader at all.

For installing plymouth theme properly follow below steps.

Download OS X Yosemite/darwin theme from [here](https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1009320/).

Unzip tarball file and copy content to `/usr/share/plymouth/themes` directory.

```
sudo cp -a darwin /usr/share/plymouth/themes/
```

Configure Plytmouth darwin theme to run on system boot.

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/share/plymouth/themes/default.plymouth default.plymouth /usr/share/plymouth/themes/darwin/darwin.plymouth" 100

sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir, it worked like a charm